# How do I get my Golang web server to run in the background?

Tags: linux, shell, daemon

I have recently completed the *Wiki web development tutorial* (http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/). I had tons of fun and I would like to experiment more with the net/http package.

However, I noticed that when I run the wiki from a console, the wiki takes over the console. If I close the console terminal or stop the process with <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd> then the server stops.

How can I get the server to run in the background? I think the term for that is running in a daemon.

I'm running this on Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

## Simple / Usable things first

If you want a start script without much effort (i.e. dealing with the process, just having it managed by the system), you could create a `systemd` service. See [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59441983/1643939) for a detailled description on how to do that.
Afterwards you can start the service with

```
systemctl start myserver
```

Previously I would have recommended trying `xinetd` or something similar for finer granuarlity regarding resource and permission management but [systemd already covers that](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html).

## Using the shell

You could start your process like this:

```
nohup ./myexecutable &
```

The `&` tells the shell to start the command in the background, keeping it in the job list.
On some shells, the job is killed if the parent shell exits using the HANGUP signal.
To prevent this, you can launch your command using the `nohup` command, which discards the HANGUP signal.

However, this does not work, if the called process reconnects the HANGUP signal.

To be really sure, you need to remove the process from the shell's joblist.
For two well known shells this can be achieved as follows:

#### bash:

```
./myexecutable &
disown <pid>
```

#### zsh:

```
./myexecutable &!
```

### Killing your background job

Normally, the shell prints the PID of the process, which then can be killed using the `kill` command, to stop the server. If your shell does not print the PID, you can get it using

```
echo $!
```

directly after execution. This prints the PID of the forked process.

Comment: Then how would I go back and stop it, or restart?

Comment: `&` will still hup the command when you close the terminal (depending on your shell). In bash, you need to run in it `screen`, `nohup`, or `disown` it after backgrounding it with `&` or `ctrl+Z`

Comment: @lunixbochs, you're probably right to not depend on the shell's behavior on that. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! I can see how a program like upstart would be handy if you forget to record the PID when you start the background process. I'm going to experiment with both techniques and report back.

Comment: I just tried `&!` with bash version 5.0.17(1)-release and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

You could use [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org) to manage your process.

Comment: Monit is another option.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu? Use [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).

Create a file in `/etc/init` for your job, named `your-service-name.conf`

```
start on net-device-up
exec /path/to/file --option
```

You can use `start your-service-name`, as well as: `stop`, `restart`, `status`

Comment: Upstart appears to have been superceded by systemd, hasnt it? How to do it now? on Ubuntu LTS 14.04

Comment: `sudo service start your-service-name` not work, service not found

Answer (score 5):

This will configure your service using `systemd`, not a comprehensive tutorial but rather a quick jump-start of how this can be set up.

Content of your `app.service` file

```
[Unit]  
Description=deploy-webhook service
After=network.target

[Service]      
ExecStart=/usr/bin/go webhook.go    
WorkingDirectory=/etc/deploy-webhook

User=app-svc      
Group=app-svc

Restart=always    
RestartSec=10    
KillSignal=SIGINT

SyslogIdentifier=deploy-webhook-service      
PrivateTmp=true  

Environment=APP_PARAM_1=ParamA
Environment=APP_PARAM_2=ParamB

[Install]      
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Starting the Service

```sh
sudo systemctl start deploy-webhook.service
```

Service Status

```
sudo systemctl status deploy-webhook.service
```

Logs

```
journalctl -u deploy-webhook -e
```

Answer (score 1):

After you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> (putting the current task to sleep) you can run the command `bg` in the terminal (stands for background) to let the latest task continue running in the background.

When you need to, run `fg` to get back to the task.

To get the same result, you can add to your command `&` at the end to start it in the background.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59441983/10907864):

To run the Go App as a service you need to create a new service unit file.

However, the App needs to know where Go is installed. The easiest way to lookup that location is by running this command:

```
which go
```

which gives you an output like this:

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go
```

With this piece of information, you can create the systemd service file. Create a file named `providus-app.service` in the `/etc/systemd/system/` using the command below:

```
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/providus-app.service
```

Next open the newly created file:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/providus-app.service
```

Paste the following configuration into your service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Providus App Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=deploy
Group=deploy

ExecStart=/usr/local/go/bin/go run main.go
WorkingDirectory=/home/deploy/providus-app

Restart=always
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT

SyslogIdentifier=providus-app-service
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When you are finished, save and close the file.

Next, reload the systemd daemon so that it knows about our service file:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Start the Providus App service by typing:

```
sudo systemctl restart providus-app
```

Double-check that it started without errors by typing:

```
sudo systemctl status providus-app
```

And then enable the Providus App service file so that Providus App automatically starts at boot, that is, it can start on its own whenever the server restarts:

```
sudo systemctl enable providus-app
```

This creates a `multi-user.target` symlink in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/providus-app.service` for the `/etc/systemd/system/providus-app.service` file that you created.

To check logs:

```
sudo journalctl -u providus-app
```

Comment: I was getting `(code=exited, status=217/USER` error until I changed the type to `Type=simple` in `.service` file.