# Error with REST HTTPS Server

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a REST Server with TLS in Golang, but the program is not working:

```
http.Handle("/", gorest.Handle())
err = http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "cert.pem", "key.pem", nil)
```

If I run it with a non-root user I get `listen tcp 127.0.0.1:443: permission denied`. Running it with root user does not show previous message but execution blocks when invoking 
ListenAndServeTLS. OS used is Linux x86_64. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Permissions

Ports <= 1024 are privileged ports. You can't use them unless you're root or have the explicit
permission to use them. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182798/why-are-ports-below-1024-privileged) for an explanation or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports) or something
you trust more.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14573592/1643939) for a solution to allow your application to open these ports without
giving them superuser permissions (which is a bad idea). Money Quote:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /opt/yourGoBinary
```

#### Blocking

`ListenAndServe` and its TLS counterpart `ListeAndServeTLS` are blocking.

The http handler returned by `gorest.Handle()` is executed concurrently when `/` is accessed.
If you want to have other code running concurrently, start a goroutine before running `ListeAndServe`
or implement different http handlers.

Example using goroutines:

```
func printStuff() {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("foo")
}

func main() {
    go printSTuff()
    log.Fatal(http.ListeAndServe(":80"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, now it's clear, I thought there was a problem with certification or similar.

Comment: I suppose (and hope) that error would've looked differently :)